# How to enable the dropdown menus (MME, Recording Channels, etc) in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, sound-editing

I'm in the process of trying to learn how to use Audacity and am watching a tutorial that has some dropdown menus below the pause, play, etc buttons:
[image]

However, in my version of Audacity that I installed I don't see those menus:
[image]

Where are those menus and is there a way I can get those menus in the same place as in the tutorial?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those dropdown menus are now **in one place**:

[image]

After clicking on the “Audio Setup” icon:

[image]

---

However, **you can display / hide menus from your tutorial** using the main menu:

*View ⇾ Toolbars ⇾ Device Toolbar:*

[image]

(Thanks [audionuma](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/11428/audionuma) for correcting me.)

Comment: It seems to be since version 3.2. Nevertheless, _Added a new Audio Setup button, replacing the Device Toolbar by default. The device toolbar can be re-added via the View > Toolbars menu._ https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Release_Notes_3.2

Comment: @audionuma, thanks for correcting me, I included it into my answer.